# How to use tess4j java 7

Tags: java, jboss, slf4j, tess4j

I'm trying to use `tess4j` ( i'm using v 3.4.6 with java 7 ) and i'm having a problem doing that.

My pom.xml contains :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's the code that s producing the error :

```java
private void processImg(BufferedImage ipimage){
    Tesseract it = Tesseract();
    it.setDatapath(PropertiesService.getProperty(PropertiesService.PROPERTIES_COMPONENTS, "tesseractServerPath") + "\\" + "tessdata");
    String str = it.doOCR(ipimage);
}
```

So when starting my JBOSS server and executing the function i have and error :

> NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger().

In a second try, i get another error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract .

Does any one know how to fix this? Thanx

Comment: yes but where is fopimage?? you got ipimage in the argument and you are trying to do that - either the argument is useless or something else - plus you need to have the jars in the path - if it can't find classes that might be it

Comment: sorrry the fopimage was a mistake . I edited the post. I think the first time, tesseract tries to initialize its logger which is causing the first error . Since the logger is initilized only one time, i can never initialize Tesseract. I don't know what is causing the slf4j error , the jars are in path and i can find the definition of the method also

Comment: Ok then you may have to name this org.slf4j

Comment: I dont know why you need this logger - if you want some logging of results you can create your own. The Tess4J itself should work.

Comment: Tess4J works fine and i'm using the cmd to perform some ocr but i wanted to use the doOCR(...) directly. Besides, the logger is called by tesseract .